# Is Destructor is mandatory in linked lists?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

I made a singly linked list program.

I want to know is there any need of destructor or default destructor will work fine ?

```
class sll
{
    node*head;
    node*tail;
public:
    sll()
    {
        head=tail=0;
    }
    sll(const sll & obj1);
    void addtohead (int x);
    void addtotail (int x);
    int deletefromhead();
    int deletefromtail();
}
```

Comment: Please don't write `= 0` for pointers. Write `= NULL` or if you have C++11 write `= nullptr`;

Comment: Destructor is strongly advised whenever you use pointers in a class.

Comment: @kfsone I've usually seen the exact opposite advice for C++03, with `=0` being preferred.

Comment: Yeah. `std::cout << "sizeof(0) " << sizeof(0) << ", sizeof(NULL) " << sizeof(NULL) << ", sizeof(void*) " << sizeof(void*) << std::endl;`. Plus, when you run into a case where 0/NULL resolves to an integer and invokes a different fingerprint than intended, it takes a lot longer to realize that the author was intending to pass a null pointer rather than a bool/int/whatever it gets cast to if they are passing '0' instead of 'NULL'.

Comment: `void func(int); void func(char*); int test() { func(0); }` vs `void func(int); void func(char*); int test() { func(NULL); }` (nullptr is designed to solve this problem, but here I'm talking about readability and maintainability).

Comment: @kfsone - `= 0` is the idiomatic way of setting a null pointer in C++ prior to C++11.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh, I know, but that doesn't change the fact that it's wrong. For me the litmus test is simple: I've only ever seen "= 0" when I've been required to look at seriously defective code that colleagues/friends have struggled with and have come to recognize it as [a]symptomatic of certain bad coding practices. `NULL` has it's own issue in that people sometimes think it's more than just a trivial `#define` but it provides useful insight to human cognition of the source. Plus it's trivial to `s/\bNULL\b/nullptr/` once your __cplusplus is > 199711L.

Comment: @kfsone - my goodness, how confident! I don't think Stroustrup agrees with you; he's the one who introduced `= 0`. And, of course, if you `#include` any standard C headers there's no guarantee that `NULL` will work. Often C defines it as `(void*)0`.

Comment: @PeteBecker this next is pure ego, but I like to think some of my arguments with him on this over the years are why we have nullptr. Emphasis, *like to think* :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

default destructor will only deallocate the memory of head and tail because sll() constructor only initialize head and tail to 0 at time of object intilization

it will not work for dynamically allocated nodes.Implement the following code in your class.

```
~sll()
{
    node *p = head;
    while (head !=NULL)
    {
        head= head -> next;
        delete p;
        p=head;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Destructors aren't mandatory, unless you are trying to develop RAII or good code.

If you don't include a destructor, then you place a burden on people who use your classes: they need to be aware that you don't have a destructor and that *they* MUST remove nodes before letting them go out of scope or destroying them.

Consider the "ifstream" class.

```
void function(const char* filename) {
    if (!haveReadFile) {
        ifstream file(filename); // create 'file' and open filename.
        if (file.good()) {      // file opened.
            readFile(file);
            haveReadFile = true;
        }
    }
    // .. other stuff.
}
```

We weren't required to perform "file.close()" or do any other clean-up here. It was all encapsulated into the contract we have with istream. When the object went away, it did the right thing.

Likewise with "std::string" -- you don't have to do

```
std::string greeting = "Hello, ";
greeting += username;
std::cout << greeting << std::endl;
greeting.freeMemory();
```

because string has a destructor, so the contract does not require you to actively manage its resources.

So: Never mind whether destructors are mandatory -- does the behavior that occurs when your class goes out of scope make sense if there is no destructor? Will there be a memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

In case the linked list is maintained for the life time of the program it should not matter, meaning unless your ll is not scoped to a function other than main. As because if  main terminates all heap memory for that process is also cleaned up. But when it scoped in a function other than main, and when you come out of that function and no more need to use the ll then the un freed nodes are still hanging there in the heap memory of the process, untill the program exits.

In general a good practice is to write destructors.